# Windows Phone Music Sample Code

Tags: windows-phone

I downloaded this

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Music-Videos-Hub-Sample-8ef80aab

deploys without error but I hear no sound.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try This, it's the simplest way to play a media file on WP 7/8 :

```
MediaPlayerLauncher objMediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
            objMediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri("SongName.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
            objMediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Install;
            objMediaPlayerLauncher.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.Pause | MediaPlaybackControls.Stop | MediaPlaybackControls.All;
            objMediaPlayerLauncher.Orientation = MediaPlayerOrientation.Landscape;
            objMediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
```